# Limit entries within column(s)

Tags: tags, parameters

Is there anyway I can limit entries within an entries tag. Not over all limit but within a particular column/row. If I have X amount of entries in a channel, I want them all to be displayed but only so many within a column.  Please and thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like that:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="test"
    disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks|relationships"
    dynamic="no"
}

    {if count%2 == 1}
    <div class="even">
    {/if}

    <p>{title}</p>

    {if count%2 == 0 || count == total_results}
    </div>
    {/if}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mufaddal's answer will split the results into 2 columns. From your question I'm assuming you want the first X entries to be in a column, then the rest elsewhere...?

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="test"
    disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks|relationships"
    dynamic="no"
    }

    {if count == 1}
        <div class="column">
    {/if}
    {if count == 6}
        </div>
        <div class="elsewhere">
    {/if}

    <p>{title}</p>

    {if count == total_results}
        </div>
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0):

Being X the number of columns you want, you can use the [modulus operator](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/conditionals.html#modulus-operator):

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="10"}
    {if count == 1 || count % X == 1}
        <div class="row">
    {/if}
            <div class="column">
                <h2>{title}</h2>
                {body}
            </div><!-- .column -->
    {if count == total_results || count % X == 0}
        </div><!--.row-->
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The modulus will give you the remainder of a division of the `count` variable by the number of columns will want. In case the remainder is `1`, the loop is starting a new row. In case it's 0, the loop is closing one.

Let's say you want 4 columns and a limit of 10, every new row will start at 5th and 9th iteration, being 1 the remainder of this positions by 4; and every row except of the last one will close at the 4th and 8th iterations, being their their remainders 0.

If you need to mark a last and incomplete row, you can use other [mathematical operators](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/conditionals.html#mathematic-operators) at the first conditional:

```
    {if count == 1 || count % X == 1}
        <div class="row{if total_results - count < X} incomplete-row{/if}">
    {/if}
```

If the remainder is 1 and the difference between the `count` and the `total_results` variables is smaller than the number of columns you want, the row will be incomplete.